# Rounding up one column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.5

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
          no_obs  price_cleaning  house_size
0         1             585          30
1         1             585          40
2         1             585          43
3         1             650          43
4         1             633          44
5         1             650          45
6         2             585          50
7         1             633          50
8         1             650          50
9         2             750          50
```

I want to round up the values in the `price_cleaning` column with this function:

`def roundup(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10`

I have tried the solution from this answer ([Applying function to Pandas dataframe by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013618/applying-function-to-pandas-dataframe-by-column)):

`cols = [col for col in  df.columns if col != 'price_cleaning']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(roundup)`

I get the following error:
TypeError: ("cannot convert the series to ", 'occurred at index no_obs')

Can anyone help me understand why this is not working? How do I apply the roundup function to the column? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are filtering the columns upside down, do this instead:

```
cols = [col for col in  df.columns if col == 'price_cleaning']
```

Now, if you need to cleanup only one columns, then no need to create `cols`. Just do:

```
df['price_cleaning'] = df['price_cleaning'].apply(roundup)
```

Comment: `apply` methods are great. However, based on your use-case, size of data, you may to benchmark with vectorized methods.

Comment: @JohnGalt I think OP is far away from your accurate remark at this point

Comment: True, that's just for posterity's sake :)

Answer (score 7):

I'd vectorize like

```
In [298]: df['p'] = (np.ceil(df.price_cleaning / 10) * 10).astype(int)

In [299]: df
Out[299]:
   no_obs  price_cleaning  house_size    p
0       1             585          30  590
1       1             585          40  590
2       1             585          43  590
3       1             650          43  650
4       1             633          44  640
5       1             650          45  650
6       2             585          50  590
7       1             633          50  640
8       1             650          50  650
9       2             750          50  750
```

For 10K rows, timings - vectorized method is ~15x times faster to `apply`

```
In [331]: %timeit (np.ceil(dff.price_cleaning / 10) * 10).astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 436 µs per loop

In [332]: %timeit dff['price_cleaning'].apply(roundup)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.86 ms per loop

In [333]: dff.shape
Out[333]: (10000, 4)
```

Atleast in this case, performance gap, with more rows, will increase.

Comment: great answer to use use np.ceil, very useful, thank you

Answer (score 3):

This might work:

```
>>> df['price_cleaning_ceiling']= df.price_cleaning.apply(lambda x: int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `apply` and `lambda` as:

```
In [6]: df['p'] = df['price_cleaning'].apply(lambda x: int(math.ceil(x / 10.0)) * 10)

In [7]: df
Out[7]: 
   no_obs  price_cleaning  house_size    p
0       1             585          30  590
1       1             585          40  590
2       1             585          43  590
3       1             650          43  650
4       1             633          44  640
5       1             650          45  650
6       2             585          50  590
7       1             633          50  640
8       1             650          50  650
9       2             750          50  750
```