# How to apply a custom function to every column of a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a data frame and I would like to create a new data frame which is 
created by applying a custom function [which takes the whole column as an input] 
to each column of this data frame. 
How can I do that?

Edit:
Let me make the question more clear.
This is my data frame and the function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cor_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.345, 0.985, 0.912, 0.645, 0.885, 0.121],
                       'B':[0.475, 0.502, 0.312, 0.231, 0.450, 0.234],
                       'C':[0.098, 0.534, 0.125, 0.984, 0.236, 0.734],
                       'D':[0.345, 0.467, 0.935, 0.074, 0.623, 0.469]})

def rtoz(r):
    z = 0.5 * np.log((1. + r) / (1. - r));
    return z
```

and I want to create a new data frame by applying this function to every column of this data frame. 
How can I do this?

Comment: With code. Please show what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Duplicate of [Applying function to Pandas dataframe by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013618/applying-function-to-pandas-dataframe-by-column)

Comment: If it's already vectorized like this you can just call the function? `rtoz(cor_df)`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution I was looking for with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013618/applying-function-to-pandas-dataframe-by-column)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cor_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.345, 0.985, 0.912, 0.645, 0.885, 0.121],
                       'B':[0.475, 0.502, 0.312, 0.231, 0.450, 0.234],
                       'C':[0.098, 0.534, 0.125, 0.984, 0.236, 0.734],
                       'D':[0.345, 0.467, 0.935, 0.074, 0.623, 0.469]})

def rtoz(r):
    z = 0.5 * np.log((1. + r) / (1. - r));
    return z

rtoz_df = pd.DataFrame() # new data frame to store r to z transformed values
cols = cor_df.columns
rtoz_df[cols] = cor_df[cols].apply(rtoz)
```

Comment: This solution is not recommended for the stated problem. You can apply a function on the entire dataframe rather than each column separately. Also, defining `cols = cor_df.columns` is sufficient, the list comprehension is redundant.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the cols variable from list comprehension to your suggestion now.

Answer (score 0):

Most common mathematical operations applied to each value are vectorisable. In this case, a Pandas dataframe is unnecessary.

Each of the below will give identical results. While the first 2 give dataframes which offer row and column labels, the last gives a NumPy array. As a compromise, if you require performance and labels, the middle option may suit your needs.

```
%timeit rtoz(df)                                           # 1.21 ms per loop
%timeit pd.DataFrame(rtoz(df.values), columns=df.columns)  # 180 µs per loop
%timeit rtoz(df.values)                                    # 33.7 µs per loop
```